Stop a Docker container from outliving its docker run command
I have a standard job management system that lets me run shell scripts as jobs, and kill them on command or when they take too long to run.
Some of my jobs turn around and run Docker containers, in the form of a docker run -ti --rm ..... command. This works fine along the happy path: I can forward any CPU and memory limits I want along to Docker to apply to the container, and when the container finishes my job finishes too.
But if the job management system wants to abort the job early, things go wrong. If it just kill -9s the docker run process, the Docker daemon doesn't notice, and the container stays running blithely un-aborted even though the job management system thinks it has stopped the job. If it sends a different signal to docker run, like SIGTERM or SIGHUP, that signal gets forwarded to the initial process in the container. But between Linux rules around default signal handlers for PID 1, and the process not necessarily being cooperative/responsive/willing to stop on any given signal, that also doesn't reliably stop the container.

Is there a way I can invoke docker run so that the daemon will detect disconnection of the connected Docker client and terminate the container in response?
Is there a particular signal I can configure my job management system to send to the docker run process for graceful termination, that will cause it to kill the connected container?


what's wrong with using docker stop - or am I misunderstanding your predicament?

You shouldn't be killing the docker run process. You should be killing the container. You can get the container PID by running docker container inspect <name_or_id> -f '{{.State.Pid}}'.
